# Submit Input from Modal into Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I would like to be able to:

1-Click on a div (1, 2, 3)

2-Open a Modal

3-Type text into the Modal text input

4-Click save

5-See that text in the .item-edit div

I have multiple divs that open a modal with an input. How do I input text into the input so that it populates the div?

I'm trying to submit the text into the `.item-edit` div.

Here is an example with multiple clickable divs that open a modal with a text input and a submit input:

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">1</div><div class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>
  <div onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">2</div><div class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>
  <div onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">3</div><div class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>
  
  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <p>Name</p>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
        <input onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" type="submit" value="SAVE">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: A input submit without form... something is wrong or maybe you do it with ajax, please show code.

Comment: Have you tried writing a separate function and attach that function to the corresponding `div`s via `addEventListener` ?

Comment: I have not tried that, but I don't know how I would do that. Can you show me how to do that via the js fiddle?

Comment: @Roy do you see the code there?

Comment: @johnny555 not the submitting code.

Comment: @Roy I'm sorry I don't follow. Should I redo the js fiddle?

Comment: try tagging this question with javascript and ajax to receive more answers? Its not really something which can be fixed with html

Comment: @johnny555 first for all, make the question again, what's the problem? what do you want to do with that input? Why your code is not working?

Comment: @Roy I fixed the question. Does this help to understand what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Look, I declare a function that pass the value from the input to the .item-edit.

```
function submitInput(){
    //Get the value from the input
    var text = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    //Assign the value to the .item-edit[item]
    //Item is declared each time you open the modal.
    document.getElementsByClassName('item-edit')[item].innerHTML = text;
}
```

Hope it help!.

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script>
var item = 0;
</script>
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';item=0;" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">1</div><div class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>
  <div onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';item=1;" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">2</div><div class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>
  <div onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';item=2;" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">3</div><div class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>
  
  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <p>Name</p>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
        <input onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none';submitInput()" type="button" value="SAVE">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
function submitInput(){
var text = document.getElementById('fname').value;
document.getElementsByClassName('item-edit')[item].innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the input text should populate only the clicked div.
Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wYEsFjJGdNhEAINs3GkL?p=preview).

I made two JS functions and a little modification in the HTML to help you solve the problem.

**showModal:** Show the modal (`id01`) and set its `data-num` attribute to the `num` parameter to know which is the clicked div.

**submitModal:** Get the input from modal (`id01`) and put it into the clicked div, by the `num` in the `data-num` attribute. It also resets the input.

**HTML:** You need to add an `id` with a number (eg.: `item-edit-1`) to the divs with the `item-edit` class to differentiate each. These numbers will be the parameters in the `showModal` functions (eg.: `showModal('1')`).

```
<script>
    function showModal(num) {

      document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById('id01').setAttribute('data-num', num);
    };

    function submitModal() {

      var inputText = document.getElementById('fname').value;
      var inputFrom = document.getElementById('id01').getAttribute('data-num');

      document.getElementById('fname').value = "";

      document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('item-edit-' + inputFrom).innerHTML = inputText;
    };
</script>
```

Using these functions in the HTML:

```
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div onclick="showModal('1')" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">1</div><div id="item-edit-1" class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>
<div onclick="showModal('2')" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">2</div><div id="item-edit-2" class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>
<div onclick="showModal('3')" class="grid-item"><div class="box-number">3</div><div id="item-edit-3" class="item-edit"></div><div class="null-object"></div></div>

<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
      <p>Name</p>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      <input onclick="submitModal()" type="submit" value="SAVE">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```